# Use Unix timestamp in Doctrine Timestampable

Tags: php, doctrine, epoch, unix-timestamp

How do I use Unix timestamps with the Doctrine Timestampable behavior? I found the following code snippet [here](http://maxgarrick.com/effective-development-using-doctrine-orm/), but I'd rather not manually add this everywhere:

```
$this->actAs('Timestampable', array(
'created' => array('name' => 'created_at',
    'type'    =>  'integer',
    'format'  =>  'U',
    'disabled' => false,
    'options' =>  array()),
'updated' => array('name'    =>  'updated_at',
    'type'    =>  'integer',
    'format'  =>  'U',
    'disabled' => false,
    'options' =>  array())));
```

Comment: Why not use the default Timestampable that uses DATETIME fields?

Comment: Easier to interact with simple epoch stamps.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a question that might get an answer easier than what I first thought, actually...

Let's begin by what you have now :

- a model class, that extends `Doctrine_Record`

  - I will call this class `Test`, for my example(s).
  - In this `Test` model, you want to use the `Timestampable` Behaviour, but with UNIX timestamps, and not `datetime` values
  - And you want this without having to write lots of configuration stuff in your models.

    *(I can understand that : less risk to forget one line somewhere and at wrong data in DB)*
- A project that is configured and everything

  - which means you know you stuff with Doctrine
  - and that I won't talk about the basics

A solution to this problem would be to not use the default `Timestampable` behaviour that comes with Doctrine, but another one, that you will define.

Which means, in your model, you will have something like this at the bottom of `setTableDefinition` method :

```
$this->actAs('MyTimestampable');
```

*(I suppose this could go in the `setUp` method too, btw -- maybe it would be it's real place, actually)*

---

What we now have to do is define that `MyTimestampable` behaviour, so it does what we want.

As Doctrine's `Doctrine_Template_Timestampable` already does the job quite well *(except for the format, of course)*, we will inherit from it ; hopefully, it'll mean less code to write **;-)**

So, we declare our behaviour class like this :

```
class MyTimestampable extends Doctrine_Template_Timestampable
{
    // Here it will come ^^
}
```

Now, let's have a look at what `Doctrine_Template_Timestampable` actually does, in Doctrine's code source :

- a bit of configuration *(the two `created_at` and `updated_at` fields)*
- And the following line, which registers a listener :

```
$this->addListener(new Doctrine_Template_Listener_Timestampable($this->_options));
```

Let's have a look at the source of this one ; we notice this part :

```
if ($options['type'] == 'date') {
    return date($options['format'], time());
} else if ($options['type'] == 'timestamp') {
    return date($options['format'], time());
} else {
    return time();
}
```

This means if the type of the two `created_at` and `updated_at` fields is not `date` nor `timestamp`, `Doctrine_Template_Listener_Timestampable` will automatically use an UNIX timestamp -- how convenient !

---

As you don't want to define the `type` to use for those fields in every one of your models, we will modify our `MyTimestampable` class.

Remember, we said it was extending `Doctrine_Template_Timestampable`, which was responsible of the configuration of the behaviour...

So, we override that configuration, using a `type` other than `date` and `timestamp` :

```
class MyTimestampable extends Doctrine_Template_Timestampable
{
    protected $_options = array(
        'created' =>  array('name'          =>  'created_at',
                            'alias'         =>  null,
                            'type'          =>  'integer',
                            'disabled'      =>  false,
                            'expression'    =>  false,
                            'options'       =>  array('notnull' => true)),
        'updated' =>  array('name'          =>  'updated_at',
                            'alias'         =>  null,
                            'type'          =>  'integer',
                            'disabled'      =>  false,
                            'expression'    =>  false,
                            'onInsert'      =>  true,
                            'options'       =>  array('notnull' => true)));
}
```

We said earlier on that our model was acting as `MyTimestampable`, and not `Timestampable`... So, now, let's see the result **;-)**

If we consider this model class for `Test` :

```
class Test extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('test');
        $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 4,
             'unsigned' => 0,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('name', 'string', 32, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => 32,
             'fixed' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('value', 'string', 128, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => 128,
             'fixed' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('created_at', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 4,
             'unsigned' => 0,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('updated_at', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 4,
             'unsigned' => 0,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->actAs('MyTimestampable');
    }
}
```

Which maps to the following MySQL table :

```
CREATE TABLE  `test1`.`test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

We can create two rows in the table this way :

```
$test = new Test();
$test->name = 'Test 1';
$test->value = 'My Value 2';
$test->save();

$test = new Test();
$test->name = 'Test 2';
$test->value = 'My Value 2';
$test->save();
```

If we check the values in the DB, we'll get something like this :

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
| id | name   | value          | created_at | updated_at |
+----+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Test 1 | My Value 1     | 1248805507 | 1248805507 |
|  2 | Test 2 | My Value 2     | 1248805583 | 1248805583 |
+----+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, we are OK for the creation of rows, it seems ;-)

---

And now, let's fetch and update the second row :

```
$test = Doctrine::getTable('Test')->find(2);
$test->value = 'My New Value 2';
$test->save();
```

And, back to the DB, we now get this :

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
| id | name   | value          | created_at | updated_at |
+----+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Test 1 | My Value 1     | 1248805507 | 1248805507 |
|  2 | Test 2 | My New Value 2 | 1248805583 | 1248805821 |
+----+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `updated_at` field has been updated, and the `created_at` field has not changed ; which seems OK too **;-)**

---

So, to make things short, fit in a couple of bullet points, and summarize quite a bit :

- Our model class acts as our own `MyTimestampable`, and not the default `Timestampable`
- Our behaviour extends Doctrine's one
- And only override it's configuration

  - So we can use it as we want, with only one line of code in each one of our models.

I will let you do some more intensive tests, but I hope this helps !

Have fun **:-)**

Comment: This is a great answer and should really be +100.

Comment: Thanks! Well, actually, it's been +100 : there was a bounty (worth 100 rep) on this question ; and my answer has been the accepted one ^^

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to use doctorine's listeners to create a unix timestamp equivalent when the record is fetched and before it is saved:

```
class Base extends Doctrine_Record_Listener
{
    public function preHydrate(Doctrine_Event $event)
    {
        $data = $event->data;

        $data['unix_created_at'] = strtotime($data['created_at']);
        $data['unix_updated_at'] = strtotime($data['updated_at']);

        $event->data = $data;
    }
}
```

This could be your base class that you extend in anything that needs created_at and updated_at functionality.

I'm sure with a little bit more tinkering you could loop through $data and convert all datetime fields  'unix_'.$field_name.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. Just create a Setter method for your field with a datetime parameter and use the tostring method to store it as integer.