# How to override preUpdate action to not modify my `updated_at` field in Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine, listener, behavior

I want to disable the automatic behaviour of changing the 'updated_at' field when an object is updated. I want to do it manually; or at least, have the posibility to disable it as wanted.

I know I can do this by building my own behaviour as in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183512/use-unix-timestamp-in-doctrine-timestampable). But I was searching for something 'cleaner' modifying a listener of the object.

- I've tried to override the preUpdate() action on the model.
- I've tried to disable the listeners, and nothing:

--

```
Doctrine::getTable('Place')->getRecordListener()->setOption('disabled', true);
// or
Doctrine::getTable('Place')->getRecordListener()->setOption('disabled', array('preUpdate'));
// As reference, I've used these two lines on a Symfony Task
```

Any more ideas, or code to look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the docs at http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/nl/behaviors:core-behaviors#timestampable if you want to  use Timestampable but not the updated portion of it just use:

```
Timestampable:
  updated:
    disabled: true
```

And add in your own updated_at field in the columns section.

Comment: i like it, and I don't even have to do any migration :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can access the listener directly from your object like this:

```
  $listenerChain = $this->getListener();

  $i = 0;

  while ($listener = $listenerChain->get($i))
  {
    if ($listener instanceof Doctrine_Template_Listener_Timestampable)
    {
      $listener->setOption('disabled', true);
      break;
    }
    $i++;
  }
```

Comment: Depending on the use case, this answer might be more relevant. As the original question was about having "the posibility to disable it as wanted".

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to do this would be to rename the `updated_at` field to something else. So that it is ignored by Doctrine.

That way, you can control the contents of the field exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the first (in our case the timstampable) listener for the record
$timestampable = $record->getListener()->get(0);

// disable setting of created_at at the timestampable listener
$timestampable->setOption(array('created' => array('disabled' => true)));
```

problem is that you have to know the position of the listener

you can also disable all listeners this way:

```
$record->getListener()->setOption('disabled',true);
```